# Return JSON on unauthorized REST service request using Spring Security 'hasPermission()'

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

I am implementing method level restriction/authorization (on **REST services**) using Spring security.
I have used the spring expression language and implemented custom Expression Evaluator.

It is working fine for me. However, if an unauthorized user tries to access the service, it is responding with a login page. Since my application is **REST based only**, I want to return only JSON data for all the requests.

How do I make it return JSON instead of the login page?(eg: `{status : Denied}`)

Here is the code Snippet:

**CustomEvaluator**

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object userId, Object permissionId) {
        List<String> permList = new MyDAO().getPermissionsForUser((String) userId);
        if(permList.contains(((String) permissionId))){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#userId, '3')")
    public String testAuthorization(Object obj, String userId){

        System.out.println("Has access to the service method....");

        return  "success";
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public @ResponseBody String testAuthorization(Object o,@RequestParam("userId") String userId){
        System.out.println("User ID = "+userId);
        String abc = service.testAuthorization(o,userId);
        return "{\"status\":\"success\"}";
    }
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </security:global-method-security>

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/auth/auth/denied" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>


    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.cjl.security.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

    <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.cjl.security.evaluators.MethodPermissionEvaluator"/>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is an `AccessDeniedException` is being thrown, so you want to configure your system to intercept that exception and instead return JSON.

You can set up an `@ExceptionHandler` method within your controller which catches the `AccessDeniedException`.  However, you probably want to do the same thing in all your controllers, so if you are using Spring 3.2, you can use `@ControllerAdvice` annotation on a separate 'advice' class and then include the `@ExceptionHandler` method in there.

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String exception(AccessDeniedException e) {
        return "{\"status\":\"access denied\"}";
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am using spring-security version 3.0.5. I added  @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class) to my controller. Still getting the same login page.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is working now. In 3.0.5 version, if I have to handle the same exception in another controller, what is the way? Duplicating the exception handling is the only way ?

Comment: You can either duplicate the handler, or you can create an abstractController which all of your other controllers extend.  You also might be able to create an aspect itd which which declares the handler for all of your controllers, though I admit I've not tried it.

Comment: AccessDeniedException will be throw, and the request will redirect to "/error" by default.

Comment: @ninja The OP asked how to return a json response.  Redirecting to /error is not a json response.

Comment: It's my fault. I try your solution, but the request redirect to the `/error` page, it doesn't work. Finally I find that the exception throw during the  `org.springframework.web.filter` will not be caught by the `@ ControllerAdvice `